# Regular expression for three word seperated by two comma

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to match all the scenario given below

Min one word without comma

Max three words separated by two "single space+comma"( ,)

each word cannot have space in it but all special characters are allowed

```
sometext, sometext, sometext-->valid
sometext-->valid
sometext, sometext-->valid

sometext, sometext, sometext, -->invalid
sometext, sometext, sometext, sometext -->invalid
sometext, -->invalid
sometext sometext, sometext sometext -->invalid
```

tried below expression but cant validate invalid scenarios

```
[a-zA-Z]*(,[a-zA-Z]*){0,2}
```

Thanks

Comment: If all special characters are allowed then why are you using `[a-zA-Z]`?

Comment: What do you mean by "all special characters"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(\w+,\s*){0,2}\w+$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lA3qP5/1)

Or to allow special character except comma and spaces use:

```
/^([^\s,]+,\s*){0,2}[^\s,]+$/gm
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^[^ ,](,\s[^ ,]){0,2}$/
```

Comment: `\1` matches the exact text that was captured most recently in group #1.  Your regex only works if all the values are identical.  I know that's true in the OP's example, but it's safe to assume it won't be in real life.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun without regex (I don't know if its faster than regex)

```
var examples = ['sometext, sometext, sometext',
'sometext',
'sometext, sometext',
'sometext, sometext, sometext,',
'sometext, sometext, sometext, sometext',
'sometext,',
'sometext sometext, sometext sometext'];

examples.forEach(function(example){
    var splitResult = example.split(', ');

    if (splitResult.length < 4 && 
        splitResult.indexOf('') === -1 && 
        splitResult.filter(function(x){return x.split(' ').length > 1}).length === 0 && 
        splitResult.filter(function(x){return x.substr(-1) === ','}).length === 0)
        console.log(example + ': valid');
    else
        console.log(example + ': not valid');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this regular expression:

```
^([a-z]+,\s{1}){0,2}[a-z]+$
```

it will match exact what you mentioned example text including space also.